# Azure pipeline push Azure main repo to github main repo

Tags: azure, github, azure-pipelines

I am trying to create pipeline that will push code from azure repository to github repository but it still wont work. (I am also using PAT token to access github repo in url and both repos are private)

```
    trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

name: Keep clone up to date

variables:
  REMOTE_ADDR: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'

stages:
  - stage: running_git_commands
    displayName: running_git_commands
    jobs:
      - job: initiate
        displayName: initiate
        continueOnError: false
        steps:
          - checkout: self
            clean: true
            persistCredentials: true
            displayName: run_commands
          - bash: | 
              git checkout main
              git remote add repoGithub $(REMOTE_ADDR)
              git fetch repoGithub main
              git reset --hard repoGithub/main
              git pull --rebase repoGithub main
              git push -f repoGithub main
```

But i am getting

```
error: pathspec 'main' did not match any file(s) known to git
From https://github.com/XXXX
 * branch            main       -> FETCH_HEAD
 * [new branch]      main       -> repoGithub/main
HEAD is now at 56894d3 Create README.md
From https://github.com/XXXXX
 * branch            main       -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up to date.
error: src refspec main does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/XXXXX'
##[error]Bash exited with code '1'.
Finishing: Bash
```

What I am doing wrong? On azure i have some code on github i have only readme.md file.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't know about the main branch `error: src refspec main does not match any`.
I would check the see if you are in detached HEAD state.
Add `git branch --list` in your script and see if that's the case.
If so, you need to
`git branch main` before `git checkout main`.

Tested on my own environment using the following git commands and it works fine.

```
    jobs:
      - job: initiate
        displayName: initiate
        continueOnError: false
        steps:
          - checkout: self
            clean: true
            persistCredentials: true
            displayName: run_commands
          - bash: | 
              git branch master
              git checkout master
              
              git remote add repoGithub $(REMOTE_ADDR)
              git fetch repoGithub
              git push -f repoGithub master:main
```

Had to do `master:main` as I had two differently named origins.

---